# Web application - getting path from class library to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, rdlc, syncfusion

Problem looks like this:

I need to get path to class library from web application(CL is referrenced to web app).
I tried to use `Server.MapPath` solution but this wasn't the best idea.

I am trying to get path to RDLC report which is in class library and when I try to move this file to web application my data source (from object) gone. Then render report doesn't looks like should. I am using `syncfusion` Report Viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your RDLC report file as assembly embedded resource. Then you can reference it on demand with `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` call.

Comment: your solution works, but I had to make some research to get how to use it.